# How does Azure Search Service know which indexer to search?

Tags: azure, search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have 5 indexers created for Azure Search Service. How does Azure Search know which indexer to search in? For example: I have indexer for the details of a purchase order, another indexer for supplier details, another indexer for categories. I searched for 999 and Azure Search searched in Detail and Supplier indexer. Why did it not search in category indexer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the search client, you need to specify which index you want to fire the searches against:

```
SearchServiceClient serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(adminApiKey));
var indexClient = serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient(indexName);
```

Comment: Yep got it. We have a json created for indexers. Have marked category indexer fields as "searchable:false". Thanks for your help